# Invalid TraceListenerData type in configuration for Enterprise Library Logging Distributor

Tags: logging, configuration, enterprise-library, msmq

I am trying to use the Enterprise Library MSMQ Distributor service to pick up log messages being placed in an MSMQ queue and place them in a database through the standard Database part of the Logging block.

However, when I try to start the Distributor service I get the following exception:

```
Exception Type: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: Invalid TraceListenerData type in configuration 'listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database"'. (C:\Projects\LogTest\msmqDistributor\MsmqDistributor.exe.Config line 15)
```

The line in question looks like this:

```
  <listeners>
   <add name="Database Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database"
    databaseInstanceName="LoggingDB" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"
    addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter"
    traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp" />
  <!-- other listeners -->
  </listeners>
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the listener definition - it seems as if the Distributor can't find it, but as far as I know the relevant dll is in the same folder. Running the same configuration against a different application works correctly and writes log entries to the database, so it seems as though it could be something to do with service permissions but I don't know which way I need to look for this one.

Comment: Double check if the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.dll is deployed.  [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) might help seeing if there area any issues locating the assembly.

Comment: @Tuzo thanks for this tip - it was pretty close to the solution to the problem, which I have included below in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem came down to having the wrong versions of .dlls available. If you have both the source and binary versions of Enterprise Library you need to ensure you use the same libraries  as the version of EntLibConfig.exe that you use to create your configuration file. So if you are using the EntLibConfig file from the binary distribution you need to make dlls from the binary distribution available to the application that is configured by them. Otherwise all your references will be tangled and you will get this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have marked this as answered but I ran into this issue and you can solve it without having to revert to another version of EntLib that matches EntLibConfig. 
In my case I was using EntLib version 5.0.505.0 and the EntLibConfig.exe needed EntLib version 5.0.414.0 like you had in you config file. Just every occurrence of version=5.0.414.0  in your config file to the right version and this will work. That should be the the Config section for loggingConfiguration and the Listener and formatter sections as well.

The draw back is that you will no longer be able to open up your config file in EntLibConfig.exe as it will try to use the older version

[image: entlibconfig error]